# When "-ing" form of verbs is not used to indicate ongoing action?

Tags: progressive-aspect

> On our next break, we head into the kitchen to find Beth **standing** over the sink, **washing** lettuce. Come to think of it, it's nice having her always right here where we left her. She points to a buffet of biscuits, brownies and some kind of amazing
>   coconut squares, only two of which are left, thanks to the Blue team, which cut the line and who we think is made up of a bunch of buffaloes anyway.

In above sentences two ing-form of verbs has been used. They are **standing** and **washing**. I think, they are not indicating ongoing actions. Sometimes ing-form of verbs is used in progressive tense, and sometimes it isn't used to indicate ongoing action. I cannot understand when it indicates ongoing actions and when it doesn't.

I would appreciate it if anybody discuss this matter elaborately.

Comment: To give a very brief answer, yes, I think that these words do indicate an ongoing action.  At the moment we head into the kitchen, Beth is in the middle of the actions of standing and washing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sometimes ing-form of verbs is used in progressive tense

Progressive (a.k.a continuous) tenses are a form of *to be* + *-ing*.

> I am walking down the street.
>
> She was going to the store.
>
> They will be working for me next week.

Without a form of *to be*, it's either a gerund (noun) or participle (modifier), or part of a noun or adjective/adverb phrase:

> The destroying of our society's morals is causing an increase in crime.
>
> Her running down the street scared my dog.
>
> Don't throw the wrench into the running machine, it will break spectacularly.

---

Regarding your example above, I think what is happening if the following:

A meaning of *find* is "to discover", and when used in this sense, it's one of a few words where the "object" is actually a *subject complement*.

For example, this sentence:

> I am thirsty

*Thirsty* is not really a direct object of *am*, but a modifier that describes the subject.  The verb here really just links the subject and modifier, but doesn't really describe an action.  *Find* is working like this in your example.

A possible meaning of an *-ing* word, when used as a modifier, is "currently X-ing" or "now X-ing".

> I found him working hard on his homework = I found him currently working hard on his homework.
>
> The running machine is causing problems = The machine that is currently running is causing problems

Which makes sense if you think about it, because continuous tenses are *to be* + *-ing* and they are used to describe an action that is currently ongoing or in progress.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in your example to indicate that Beth is not **standing** and **washing** the lettuce. So, to me, she is pictured doing those things. If the text read

> ...head into the kitchen where we **usually find** Beth **standing** over the sink, **washing** lettuce.

Then I would understand there might not be any **ongoing action**